# Apache Camel- component that returns value

Tags: apache-camel

In camel , Processor interface has the following api:

```
public interface Processor{
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception;
}
```

In camel, is there any component that returns value similar to that given below:

```
public interface ComponentThatReturns<T>{
    public T result(Exchange exchange) throws Exception;
}
```

Comment: What would you use that value for? Could you elaborate more on your use case?

Answer (score 0):

Processors in Camel can store any needed values as either message headers or exchange properties.

If you had a component that returned a different type as you describe, something would still need to get that value into the Exchange to pass it to the next step in the route.